# Can not call Public List from App_Code folder in Web Form

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, static-methods, generic-list

So here's my predicament. I'm writing a custom, one-off content management system, and I can not for the life of me getting this method to work correctly. What I want to do is create a laundry list worth of methods in separate folders and call them as I need them on whichever web forms I want to call them on.

I created a WebApp and created a folder inside of the app called App_Code. Inside of App_Code, there is a public class called "TestimonialService". Here it is:

```
/******************** TESTIMONIAL SERVICE ****************/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code.Data;

namespace BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code.Testimonials
{
public class TestimonialService
{
    private readonly CMSObjectContext _context;
    public TestimonialService(CMSObjectContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    #region methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all testimonials
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>testimonial collection</returns>
    public List<Testimonial> GetAllTestimonials()
    {
        var query = from t in _context.Testimonials
                    orderby t.DisplayOrder ascending
                    select t;
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            var testimonial = query.ToList();
            return testimonial;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    #endregion
    }
}
```

Then on the actual aspx.cs page I call said function like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code;
using BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code.Data;
using BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code.Testimonials;

namespace BlueTreeSecurity
{
    public partial class Testimonials : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Page.Title = "Testimonials | ...";

            Bind_Data();
    }

    protected void Bind_Data()
    {
        /** when i try to use intellisense here it's not recognized. **/

        var testimonials = TestimonialService.GetAllTestimonials();

        rptTestimonials.DataSource = testimonials;
        rptTestimonials.DataBind();
    }
}
```

}

The exact error spat back is this:

```
Error   1   
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
'BlueTreeSecurity.App_Code.Testimonials.TestimonialService.GetAllTestimonials()'
```

Anything would be appreciated, guys. I'm ripping my hair out here.

Here's the Project structure

```
- Blue Tree Security (main project)
   - App_Code
      +  Data
      +  Testimonials
         + TestimonialService.cs
   Rest of the .aspx, .aspx.cs, and .ascx files.
```

Comment: You are trying to use the `GetAllTestimonials` method as static on the `TestimonialService` class. You need to instantiate the `TestimonialService` class first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not totally misinterpreting here, the error message you are getting is telling you what the problem is. Make GetAllTestimonials() static or instantiate a TestimonialService instance.

```
protected void Bind_Data()
{
    var testimonialService = new TestimonialService(yourContextObect);

    var testimonials = testimonialService.GetAllTestimonials();

    rptTestimonials.DataSource = testimonials;
    rptTestimonials.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Till I'm so close. What is this yourContextObject you're talking about. Is that the CMSContextObject I have referred to in the class?

Comment: It's a CMSObjectContext object. The constructor of your TestimonialService class expects it as a parameter. I cannot tell you where to get that from since i don't know your code. If you don't have access to your current CMSObjectContext object in Bind_Data you will have to make it available in one way or another or you need change your TestimonialService class to grab the context by itself instead of having it get passed in as param. Which solution is to be preferred depends on multiple factors which cannot be evaluated by just a few code snippets on stack overflow.